# how detect mousewheel support ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How detect support  mousewheel  event in browser and filterd mobile ?

Is it correct ?  :

```
var  supportwheel = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : false
```

Comment: realy ?  maybe not equal question ?

Comment: if you can detect the browser and OS then you should be able to know which mousewheel event is supported from the possible duplicate question though right? so this is probably more of a question of how to browser sniff?